# mYSQL add int costant to select result

Tags: mysql, select

I'm try to change the result value with this select
Rate is a decimal(9.7)

```
SELECT 
    rate
FROM 
    transaction * 0.95
```

This query return error #1064 - sintax error for the right syntax to use near '* 0.95'

Can help me?

Comment: You mean `select rate * 0.95 from transaction` - transaction is a table name and you can't multiply tables and numbers

Comment: What is `transaction * 0.95`?

Comment: i didn't  get the query structure at all.

Comment: sorry my wrong 
The select correct is
SELECT 
    rate* 0.95
FROM 
    transaction
and that work good :p